# How to fetch required data using sql?

Tags: mysql

```
 c1  c2    c3
------------------
 D1    1        1

 D1    1        2

 D1    2        3

 D1    2        4

 D2    1        5

 D2    1        6

 D2    2        7

 D2    2        8
```

How to get this ?

```
 c1   c2     c3
-----------------
 D1   1       2

 D1   1       2

 D2   2       2

 D2   2       2
```

Using this query

> Select c1,c2,count(c3) From t1 WHERE  c1  in (SELECT c1 FROM t1 group
>   by c1) GROUP by c2 ;

Comment: I don't see how you get this result set, as it contains a record which does not even appear in the sample data.

Comment: using the same query i am not getting what i required

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is required?

Comment: Issue resolved, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c1, c2, COUNT(c3) FROM table GROUP BY c1, c2;
```